# .Net Core 3.1 dynamic multiple filtering of products

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Multiple checkbox filter **(dynamic)**

**filter**=blue:1,red:1,ram16gb:2,ram38gb:2

**.netcore 3.1 Error**: could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SearchOption searchOption, int pageSize = 10)
    {

        var query = _productRepo.Query()
            .Include(x => x.AttributeValues)
            .Where(x => x.InActive == true);


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchOption.filter))
        {

            var list = searchOption.filter.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(item =>
                   {
                       var subItems = item.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                       return new SplitFilter
                       {
                           AttributeId = Convert.ToInt64(subItems[1]),
                           Search = subItems[0],
                       };
                   }).ToList();

            if (list?.Any() == true)
            {
                var attr = _modelAttributeValueRepository
                    .GetFind(x => list.Any(j => j.Search == x.Value && j.AttributeId == x.AttributeId))
                    .Select(x => x.ProductId);
          
                query = query.Where(x => attr.Contains(x.ProductId));
            }
        }
        
        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where you put these codes? These codes is working well inside the controller.

Comment: written in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code worked.✓**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SearchOption searchOption, int pageSize = 10)
    {

        var query = _productRepo.Query()
            .Include(x => x.AttributeValues)
            .Where(x => x.InActive == true);


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchOption.filter))
        {
            var list = searchOption.filter.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(item =>
                   {
                       var subItems = item.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                       return new SplitFilter
                       {
                           AttributeId = Convert.ToInt64(subItems[1]),
                           Search = subItems[0],
                       };
                   })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.AttributeId).Select(x => new { AttributeId = x.Key, List = x.Select(j => j.Search) })
                   .ToList();

            if (list?.Any() == true)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    var attr = _modelAttributeValueRepository
                        .GetFind(x => item.AttributeId == x.AttributeId && item.List.Contains(x.Value))
                        .Select(x => x.ProductId)
                        .ToList();

                    query = query.Where(x => attr.Contains(x.ProductId));
                }
            }
        }

        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this

```
var attr = _modelAttributeValueRepository
                    .GetFind(x => list.Any(j => j.Search == x.Value && j.AttributeId == x.AttributeId))
                    .Select(x => x.ProductId)
                    .ToList(); // add this line 
          
query = query.Where(x => attr.Contains(x.ProductId));
```

You can also rewrite your query like this:

```
query = query.Where(x => attr.Any(z => z == x.ProductId));
```

Comment: And the exception is the same?